# Django admin - how to change choices in inlines?

Tags: django, django-admin

How can I change choices of a field in Inlines class? I can't use formfield_for_choice_field in Inlines, so what to use?
I must generate it in admin, because I need request to be passed.

Comment: Inline uses a simple form, so you can do anything with that form. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I need to change choice list of 1 field in inlines. I can't do that in model, because I have to use request to check user permissions and registered models in admin. Is it possible somehow to pass request to form and then do some modifications of that field in custom inline form?

Comment: it is your field a foreignkey?

Answer (score 5):

if your field is a IntegerField or Charfield with the choices attribute, you can override the **formfield_for_choice_field** method in your inline class with something like this:

```
class YourInline(admin.StackedInline): # or TabularInline
    model = YourModelName

    def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME':
            kwargs['choices'] = (('', '---------'), ('1', 'Choice1'), ('2', 'Choice2'))
        return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
```

good luck

Comment: I tried that, but while saving and field in model has no choices parameter it can't be saved and I get __init__ error. When I put empty choices there in model and use solution You gave, I get error, that selected choice is wrong :/

Comment: you have to put one option at least e.g. ((1, '1'),), then the above method will override that choices.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow. I see one difference between your solution and the one shown in docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3//ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_choice_field). You return
`db_field.formfield(**kwargs)` when field found while docs say to return only
`super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_choice_field(db_field, request, **kwargs)`.
Hope it will work :)

Comment: Nope:/ I get **_Value u'1' is not a valid choice._** when i try to select item, so it doesn't work. It gets choices declared in model in that way.

Answer (score 3):

in my case, the form option must be filled, hope help anyone.

```
# admin.py
class YourInlineForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = YourModelName
        widgets = {
            'level': forms.widgets.Select(
                choices = (
                    (0,'A'),
                    (1,'B'),
                    (2,'C'),
                ),
            )
        }

# admin.py
class YourInline(admin.StackedInline): # or TabularInline
    model = YourModelName
    form = YourInlineForm

    def formfield_for_choice_field(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME':
            kwargs['choices'] = (('', '---------'), ('1', 'Choice1'), ('2', 'Choice2'))
        return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with eos87's answer. It is only a partial solution however. When saving, a validation error occurs since the original model's choices are being used for validation. To solve that problem, add this function to your model as well:

```
def clean_fields(self, exclude=None):
    exclude.append('YOUR_FIELD_NAME') # we will do our own validation on this field
    super(YOUR_MODEL, self).clean_fields(exclude = exclude)

    value = self.YOUR_FIELD_NAME
    if value and not self.validChoice(value):
        msg = 'Select a valid choice. %s is not one of the available choices.'
        errors = {''YOUR_FIELD_NAME'': ([msg % value])}
        raise ValidationError(errors)

def validChoice(self, value):
  # add your validation code here
```